# Java pointer exception

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to traverse an array of Student objects in my main function class but am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at input_output.printOutClass(input_output.java:36)
    at input_output.main(input_output.java:11)
```

line 36 in my input_output file looks like

```
 34  for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
 35    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
 36    students[i].getFullPrint();
 37    System.out.println("");
 38  }
```

after some debugging I'm pretty sure once the once the code runs line 36 in the iteration in which students[i] did not have a constructor called on it. i'm new to java however and don't know how to check the memory address of a variable to see if it exists. How do i do this?

thanks in advanced.

Comment: the array items are null, post the full code or the part you create the instance of the array

Comment: Can you share the code where you are populating the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it means that students[i] is returning null.

try this.

```
             for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
                     System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
                     System.out.println( i + (students[i] == null));
                     if(students[i] != null){
                         students[i].getFullPrint();
                     }
                     System.out.println("");
             }
```

IDE's allow debugging put a break point in and it will should give you memory and variable states.

Comment: You may mark his answer as an answer to this question. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

In Java, pointers are called references. You can avoid referencing an object that has not been created like this:

```
if (students[i] != null) {
    students[i].getFullPrint();
}
```

Alternatively, you can make sure that all objects inside the `students[]` array have been created. Note that in Java when you create an array, you create only the structure to hold references to objects; you do not create objects themselves - they need to be created separately by calling their constructors and assigning the individual array elements.

Answer (score 0):

check if the reference equals to `null`:

```
if(students[i] != null) // blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not initialized your `students[]` array.

What my guess is that you have used the following line somewhere in your code to declare students[] array.

```
StudentClass students[] = new StudentClass[some_int];
```

But you'd not initiliazed it like the below code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
            students[i] = new StudentClass();
        }
```

This is a very common mistake. So please make sure that you have initialized your references properly.